# TCP Proxy Using Python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am studying [Black Hat Python](https://www.nostarch.com/blackhatpython) and trying to understand the TCP proxy code.

I now almost understand it, but it doesn't quite work when I try to test it with

```
python proxy.py localhost 21 ftp.target.ca 21 True
```

in one terminal and

```
ftp ftp.target.ca 21
```

in another.

In the first terminal, I get only listen on localhost on port 21 and nothing else; and in the second terminal, it's happen connection between me and server and I wrote username and password.

The packages that transfer between me and server should appear in the first terminal.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
import sys
import socket
import threading



# this is a pretty hex dumping function directly taken from
# http://code.activestate.com/recipes/142812-hex-dumper/
def hexdump(src, length=16):
    result = []
    digits = 4 if isinstance(src, unicode) else 2

    for i in xrange(0, len(src), length):
       s = src[i:i+length]
       hexa = b' '.join(["%0*X" % (digits, ord(x))  for x in s])
       text = b''.join([x if 0x20 <= ord(x) < 0x7F else b'.'  for x in s])
       result.append( b"%04X   %-*s   %s" % (i, length*(digits + 1), hexa, text) )

    print b'\n'.join(result)


def receive_from(connection):

        buffer = ""

    # We set a 2 second time out depending on your 
    # target this may need to be adjusted
    connection.settimeout(2)

        try:
                # keep reading into the buffer until there's no more data
        # or we time out
                while True:
                        data = connection.recv(4096)

                        if not data:
                                break

                        buffer += data


        except:
        pass

        return buffer

# modify any requests destined for the remote host
def request_handler(buffer):
    # perform packet modifications
    return buffer

# modify any responses destined for the local host
def response_handler(buffer):
    # perform packet modifications
    return buffer


def proxy_handler(client_socket, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first):

        # connect to the remote host
        remote_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        remote_socket.connect((remote_host,remote_port))

        # receive data from the remote end if necessary
        if receive_first:

                remote_buffer = receive_from(remote_socket)
                hexdump(remote_buffer)

                # send it to our response handler
        remote_buffer = response_handler(remote_buffer)

                # if we have data to send to our local client send it
                if len(remote_buffer):
                        print "[<==] Sending %d bytes to localhost." % len(remote_buffer)
                        client_socket.send(remote_buffer)

    # now let's loop and reading from local, send to remote, send to local
    # rinse wash repeat
    while True:

        # read from local host
        local_buffer = receive_from(client_socket)


        if len(local_buffer):   

            print "[==>] Received %d bytes from localhost." % len(local_buffer)
            hexdump(local_buffer)

            # send it to our request handler
            local_buffer = request_handler(local_buffer)

            # send off the data to the remote host
            remote_socket.send(local_buffer)
            print "[==>] Sent to remote."


        # receive back the response
        remote_buffer = receive_from(remote_socket)

        if len(remote_buffer):

            print "[<==] Received %d bytes from remote." % len(remote_buffer)
            hexdump(remote_buffer)

            # send to our response handler
            remote_buffer = response_handler(remote_buffer)

            # send the response to the local socket
            client_socket.send(remote_buffer)

            print "[<==] Sent to localhost."

        # if no more data on either side close the connections
        if not len(local_buffer) or not len(remote_buffer):
            client_socket.close()
            remote_socket.close()
            print "[*] No more data. Closing connections."

            break

def server_loop(local_host,local_port,remote_host,remote_port,receive_first):

        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        try:
                server.bind((local_host,local_port))
        except:
                print "[!!] Failed to listen on %s:%d" % (local_host,local_port)
                print "[!!] Check for other listening sockets or correct permissions."
                sys.exit(0)

        print "[*] Listening on %s:%d" % (local_host,local_port)


        server.listen(5)        

        while True:
                client_socket, addr = server.accept()

                # print out the local connection information
                print "[==>] Received incoming connection from %s:%d" % (addr[0],addr[1])

                # start a thread to talk to the remote host
                proxy_thread = threading.Thread(target=proxy_handler,args=(client_socket,remote_host,remote_port,receive_first))
                proxy_thread.start()

def main():

    # no fancy command line parsing here
    if len(sys.argv[1:]) != 5:
        print "Usage: ./proxy.py [localhost] [localport] [remotehost] [remoteport] [receive_first]"
        print "Example: ./proxy.py 127.0.0.1 9000 10.12.132.1 9000 True"
        sys.exit(0)

    # setup local listening parameters
    local_host  = sys.argv[1]
    local_port  = int(sys.argv[2])

    # setup remote target
    remote_host = sys.argv[3]
    remote_port = int(sys.argv[4])

    # this tells our proxy to connect and receive data
    # before sending to the remote host
    receive_first = sys.argv[5]

    if "True" in receive_first:
        receive_first = True
    else:
        receive_first = False


    # now spin up our listening socket
    server_loop(local_host,local_port,remote_host,remote_port,receive_first)

main()
```

Comment: Hi @AN HA. What is the license on this code?

Answer (score 0):

Simply running a proxy server on port 21 won't make the ftp client use it - so you shouldn't be trying to connect to the remote host. if the commandline is running the proxy on for example 9000, then ftp to that port i.e. localhost 9000 and the proxy will forward communication to/from that remote host.

Comment: i changed the ftp port to 1234 in proftpd.conf is that what you mean and nothing happen i wrote python proxy.py localhost 1234 ftp.target.ca 21 True and the same result

Comment: Try instead of ftp ftp.target.ca 21 doing ftp localhost 21 (assuming you are running the proxy on the same host) because the proxy.py command line tells it to forward port 21 to ftp.target.ca

Comment: like this python proxy.py localhost 1234 localhost 1234 True and in another terminal ftp localhost 1234 ? how it or i understand wrong

Comment: No. python proxy.py localhost 1234 ftp.target.ca 21 True and in another terminal on the same host ftp localhost 1234

Comment: how can i listen on the same port twice at the same time localhost 1234 would listen on 1234 and localhost (server) would listen on the same port would say to me port is busy

Comment: See my reply above - you won't be listening on the same port twice.

Comment: it recieve connection =D but when server ask username and i wrote it ... the server said 421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection
Login failed.
No control connection for command: Transport endpoint is not connected

Comment: Excellent. Clearly the proxy is now forwarding communication to the remote server. Your login failure sounds like a different problem. Does the service work when you try to connect without the proxy?

Comment: the proxy say [*] Listening on localhost:1234 
[==>] Received incoming connection from 127.0.0.1:56223
some data
[<==] Sending 37 bytes to localhost.
[*] No more data. Closing connections.
so the server say service not found because the proxy end the connection

Comment: the service work without the proxy the problem is the proxy end the connection why

Comment: Ftp error 421:421  Error 421 Service not available, closing control connection. Error 421 User limit reached Error 421 You are not authorized to make the connection Error 421 Max connections reached Error 421 Max connections exceeded  This can be a reply to any command if the service knows it must shut down. Try loggin

Comment: Try telnet to your localhost port 1234 (or whatever it is in the proxy.py port setting) - you should see more of the ftp login process and be able to do it. Compare with trying to telnet to the remote server port 21 (or whatever the ftp port is on the remote server).

Comment: in normal way when i wrote ftp ftp.target.ca 1234 it ask me for user then i write it then it ask me for pass then i write it then the server said failed login but in my case the server just send the first package and the proxy end the connection even before i write the username

Comment: when i try telnet or ftp to ftp.target.ca it connect and everything is good and when i try to connect to localhost 1234 through ftp or telnet it doesn't connect

Comment: Are you sure this proxy code works in this scenario? AFAICT the code below if not len(local_buffer) or not len(remote_buffer): means that as soon as there is no data to receive or send it closes the connection - so when you pause to type your login/password it closes the connection. Also if you get beyond the authentication, when you go to receive/send a file, FTP protocol needs another port connection (and therefore another dynamically-constructed proxy) for the file transfer - if ftp proxy is what you are trying to do you will have to read up on the ftp protocol and active/passive mode.

Comment: This seems to be accurate Barny. When I run the code right from the books website with ./proxy.py 127.0.0.1 23 127.0.0.1 21 True and then using ftp to connect ftp 127.0.0.1 23 the connection dies at the point where I am prompted to enter credentials.